# Multiline json data into logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following JSON structure that I want to parse with Logstash:

```html
{
  "messages" : [ {
    "remoteReferenceId" : "133883",
    "sender" : {
      "name" : "User1"
    }
  }, {
    "remoteReferenceId" : "133894",
    "sender" : {
      "name" : "User2"
    }
  } ],
  "timestamp" : "2021-03-20T15:36:01.868+02:00"
}
```

my config is the following one:

```html
input {
  file {
    mode => "read"
    path => "/path-to-data/*.json"
    file_completed_action => "delete"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    type => "json"
    codec => multiline {
        pattern => "remoteReferenceId"
        negate => true
        what => previous
        auto_flush_interval => 1
        multiline_tag => ""
     }
  }
}
filter{
    json{
        source => "messages"
        target => "parsedJson"
    }
    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "remoteReferenceId" => "%{[remoteReferenceId]}"
          }
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
        index => "index_messages"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The JSON file is imported in Elasticsearch. My problem is that I want to add a new field "remoteReferenceId" with the value of the node (e.g. value "133883" above), but in Elastic I get instead "%{[remoteReferenceId]}" and not the real value.

What can be the problem?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

I believe your pipeline is not going to work ever.
The json plugin is failing as the string your multiline extract is not valid json.

## Solution:

Could you try this pipeline ?:

```rb
input {
  file {
    mode => "read"
    path => "/tmp/*.json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline
    {
        pattern => '^\{'
        negate => true
        what => previous                
    }
  }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }

    split { field => "[messages]" }

    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "remoteReferenceId" => "%{[messages][remoteReferenceId]}"
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paulo, I have now a case where I get a JSON with a single entry like this 
{
    "remoteReferenceId" : "133883",
     "sender" : {
      "name" : "User1"
     }
  }
How can I modify the config above to import it? Thanks

Comment: I guess you do not need to split then.